# Invocable Process builder: Prior value

Tags: process-builder

Our org has far too many processes running on the lead object. I think we have 20 or so. I have been told it is better to have a "trigger" process builder that invokes the other process builders.

So I have tried to do so, and have come across an issue with PRIORVALUE. Can you not use this function with invocable processes? IF that is the case, I seem to only have a few options, is this true?

1. Create the process builder to be triggered on record update (not invocable)
2. Create this in APEX
3. Create a dummy field to populate the value and then compare against
4. Create a trigger, but then create a different process builder to handle each individual scenario of how I would want the data manipulated

Are these the only options? Or perhaps is there a way to get the prior value? Most of these options seem like a lot of extra work.

--edit--
For clarity, the different PBs are all completely different. This one currently lives in a single PB. The others perform completely different functions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You could do it all in one process builder instead of 20 different ones called from a single pb source. I'm not sure who told you 1 "trigger" pb was the right path but that's very much not what I would do. If you really do have that many PB's running I would advise a consolidated PB or using a trigger. PB's are great but they are more difficult to optimize than apex code.

Comment: Oh, for clarity, the different PBs are all completely different. This one currently lives in a single PB. The others perform completely different functions. Sorry for the confusion.